# Bad Request [400], FCM Legacy HTTP API with Retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit, retrofit2

URL = https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Request Body

```
{
"registration_ids": ["token 1","token 2"],
"priority": "high",
"notification": {
"title": "Divine Public School",
"body": "Test Message."
} }
```

Header

```
{
"Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: key=<myServerKey>"
}
```

I am getting status code 200 and even receiving notification in client app when hitting this url from Postman. But when I am trying to do the same in android using retrofit , I am getting status 400 Bad Request.

Android code below

```
interface NotificationService {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: key=<my server key>")
@POST("fcm/send")
fun sendNotification(@Body body: NotificationBody): Call<ResponseBody> }
```

Data Class

```
data class NotificationBody(
@SerializedName("registration_ids")
var registration_ids : ArrayList<String>,
@SerializedName("priority")
var priority:String,
@SerializedName("notification")
var notification:Notification  )

data class Notification(
@SerializedName("title")
var title:String,
@SerializedName("body")
var body:String     )
```

Retrofit Call

```
val generalRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/")
.build()!!

val service = generalRetrofit.create(NotificationService::class.java)
val data = NotificationBody(....)
val call = service.sendNotification(data)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {}
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>,response: Response<ResponseBody>)                  
{
 Log.d("TAG", response.code().toString())
 })
```

Log output of NotificationBody object

> D/TAG: NotificationBody(registration_ids=[cxd-PHM-QOyLcnLcPozjKA:APA91bGIG-NDg-hSYMlTGWm-ZVaM0hR7Om77CaksvZ4bLDKM0gU_xYk9_Um1aOzPExGR40FeHAqQpkjt_7-HiG8SMPtF5HLrUjCrcD4Asq_ZcEv-Du5AcMthcYjaZjisduLkBPhgPH0b], priority=higher, notification=Notification(title=Divine Public School, body=Hello))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an appropriate solution but made an end-point in my existing Node project.
Any one having this issue can use this.
URL https://pankaj-oil-api.herokuapp.com/notify

You need to post this object on above url.
"registration_ids" is a string array that can have minimum 1 and maximum 1000 tokens.

```
{
"registration_ids" : ["Client Token 1","Client Token 2"],
"serverKey": "<Your (Authorization) Server Key Here>",
"title": "<Enter your Notification Title here >",
"msg":"<Enter your Notification Message here >"
}
```

[Code](https://github.com/buuzuu/POI-API/blob/production/routes/firebaseNotification.js)

This is just a temporary solution . Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Made with rxJava, it will works. Important point is using 'condition'

```
 interface NotificationService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: key=<my server key>")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    fun sendNotification(@Body body: NotificationBody): Single<Any> }
```

Data class

```
data class NotificationMultipleBody(
        @SerializedName("condition")
        var condition : String,
        @SerializedName("priority")
        var priority:String,
        @SerializedName("notification")
        var notification:Notification
    )
    
    data class Notification(
        @SerializedName("body")
        var body:String,
        @SerializedName("sound")
        var sound:String
        )
```

Retrofit

```
class ApiClient {
    private val BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/"
        private val api = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(NotificationHelper::class.java)
    
    fun sendNotification(tokens:ArrayList<String>,msg: String): Single<Any> {
            var topicStr = ""
            tokens.forEachIndexed { index, str ->
                topicStr += if(index==tokens.size-1){
                    "'$str' in topics"
                } else {
                    "'$str' in topics || "
                }
            }
            val notif = Notification(
                msg,"default"
            )
            val notifBody = NotificationMultipleBody(
                topicStr,"high",notif
            )
            return api.sendNotification(notifBody)
        }
}
```

Notification Sending part

```
private val pushHelper = ApiClient()
private val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
private val tokenList = ArrayList<String>()
        disposable.add(pushHelper.sendNotification(tokenList,message).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(
                        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeWith(object :
                        DisposableSingleObserver<Any>(){
                        override fun onSuccess(t: Any) {
                            binding.btnBackFriend.performClick()
                            Log.d("logD","multiple notification sent success")
                            Log.d("logD","$t")
                        }
        
                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            binding.btnBackFriend.performClick()
                            Log.d("logD","sent fail")
                            val error = e as HttpException
                            Log.d("logD", "${error.response()?.errorBody()?.string()}")
                        }
                    }))
```